# How to change geom_text to percentage in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to convert the decimal points from the colomn titled cover_type_ratio below into a percentage in ggplot2. Here is the df

[DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgzUw.png)

And here is my code for my bar graph:

```
plot<-ggplot(coverType_count, aes(x=Cover_Type, y=count)) + 
geom_bar(stat="identity") + 
scale_y_continuous() +
geom_text(data=coverType_count,aes(label=count,y=count+100),size=4) + 
geom_text(data=coverType_count, 
aes(label=cover_type_ratio,y=count+200),size=4)+
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=30,hjust=1,size=8))+ 
ggtitle('Cover Type Distribution')
```

When plotted, it looks like this:

[Screenshot of Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VphkW.png)

I need to change the jumbled numbers to percentages from the aforementioned cover_type_ratio column in df, and have tried using the scales library, but to no avail. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Does `percent(cover_type_ratio)` help? It's a function from `scales`. You could always use `sprintf` to define a custom format.

Comment: @spinodal that worked! Thanks so much!